# How to convert ulaw format file to wav format reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wav, mu-law

I am trying to play .ulaw format in reactjs, I didn't find any straight forward way to play the  ulaw file. So I tried to convert ulaw format to wav, by using the wavfile plugin. But after conversion it playing different noise, I am not able to identify where is the actual error.

ulaw file details:

Sample Rate  8000

Bit rate 64

Channel MONO

```
import voice from '../src/app/components/voice.ulaw'
const WaveFile = require('wavefile').WaveFile;

let wav = new WaveFile();


const playUlawFile = () => {
    fetch(voice)
        .then(r => r.text())
        .then(text =>  Buffer.from(text, "utf-8").toString("base64"))
        .then(result =>{
            wav.bitDepth = '128000'
            wav.fromScratch(1, 8000, '64', result);
            wav.fromMuLaw();
            wav.toSampleRate(64000);
        return wav;

        }).then(wav => {
            audio = new Audio(wav.toDataURI())
            return audio;
        }).then(audio => {
            audio.play();

        })
}
```

Comment: `wav.fromScratch` is passed `8000` which is very low, should be around `44000`

Comment: @frozen even after setting it to 44000, some other noise is playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below changes worked for me, still some noise is there, but it can produce 80% matching sound.

```
const readFile = () => {
    fetch(voice)
        .then(r => r.text())
        .then(text =>  btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(text)))         )
        .then(result =>{
            wav.fromScratch(1, 18000, '8m', Buffer.from(result, "base64"));
            wav.fromMuLaw(32);
           wav.toSampleRate(64000, {method: "sinc"});
           return wav;
        }).then(wav => {
            audio = new Audio(wav.toDataURI())
            return audio;
        }).then(audio => {
            audio.play();
        })
}
```